# Mysql subquery for sum all columns in inner Join

Tags: mysql, join

I am attempting to get the sum of 12 columns (in same table) in a subquery in an inner join. 
Here is a link to my schema :

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62de4/1)

The query I am attempting to use is this:

```
SELECT 
`inventory`.`part_number`,
`inventory`.`qty`,
`inventory`.`description`,
`reorder`.`reorder_point` * '1' `point`,
`inventory`.`cost`,
`vendor`.`name` AS `vendor_name`,    SELECT (SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_1_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_2_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_3_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_4_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_5_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_6_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_7_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_8_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_9_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_10_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_11_Month_Prior`)+SUM(`saleshistory`.`Sales_12_Month_Prior`) AS TTL
FROM `inventory`
LEFT JOIN `reorder` ON `inventory`.`part_number` = `reorder`.`part_number`
LEFT JOIN `vendor` ON `inventory`.`vendor` = `vendor`.`vendor_id`
INNER JOIN `saleshistory` ON `saleshistory`.`location` =     `inventory`.`location` AND `saleshistory`.`part_number` = `inventory`.`part_number`
WHERE `inventory`.`qty` <= `reorder`.`reorder_point`
AND `inventory`.`location` = '99'
AND `reorder`.`reorder_point` != '0'
GROUP BY `inventory`.`part_number`
ORDER BY `vendor`.`name` ASC
```

When using this query, it returns all the values for all the records not just the rows.

Comment: I can't see why you would need that sub`SELECT`. You have not pasted the query completely, there is a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: it returns the SUM for all values in the table, not just the selected rows

Comment: Your fiddle does no SUM, and your query here is invalid.